# Why is this jquery autocomplete script do not care about the matching?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get this script work for hours. I'm done with a part of it, but the script is not taking care the matching.

So when I start to type in something, it will show up all the data from the database, even if it not match. If my database have 3 record, I going to see all, nevermind what I'm writing in.

**Here are my records:**

```
Idoya idoya@xxxx.com 123 Livingston Road xxxxxxx, XX YYYYY
Gideon gideon@xxxx.com 123 Wild Rose St. xxxxxxx, XX YYYYY 
Collin collin@xxx.com 123 Inverness Street xxxxxx, XX YYYYY
```

**And my script:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#name').autocomplete({
        source: function(data, cb){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php/PersonData/get_people',
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    name:data.term
                },
                success: function(res){
                    //cb(res);

                    var d = $.map(res, function(row){
                        return {
                            label: row.name + " " + row.mail,
                            value: row.name,
                            mail: row.mail,
                            address: row.address
                        }
                    });

                    cb(d);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value)
            $('#mail').val(ui.item.mail)
            $('#address').val(ui.item.address);
        }
    });


});
```

I want it to work like when I start to write *"Ido"* it just should to show up that one record with *"Idoya Vinay"*.

Comment: Could be your `index.php/PersonData/get_people` script not returning the correct values, have you checked that it works as it should?

Comment: You shouldn't post people data here on the web - I've corrected your data.

Comment: @jeff great job

Comment: @AME I shall ask you two very important questions. 
1. Is the api programmed to do matching?
2. Are you sending data to api in the format the api is expecting it?

Comment: @jeff It was random generated data.

Comment: @NeelBhanushali I did it based on a tutorial, and there it works fine. The data coming from a database with a simple select in an array, and I return it with json_encode.

Comment: @NeelBhanushali The jquery should to take care the matching or am I wrong?

Comment: @AME can you give me the link to the tutorial?

Comment: @NeelBhanushali  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GC6rCa0RM0
The only difference is that I have multiple field.

Comment: @NeelBhanushali But if I pick one of them, the autocomplete works fine.

Comment: @AME i shall look into it and add an answer to this stackoverflow question.

Comment: I see where is the problem, I see now it works like that after every tyiped in char it asks for the database, for a new result, but in my db query I do not take care about that. I'm using CodeIgniter, now I try to solve this there.

Comment: @AME I have added a new answer to the question. Check it and upvote if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script sends a request to the given url for data after every typed in charachter, with the ***name*** parameter. The problem was that, I didn't take care about filter the data, because I though that it will request after when I finished with the typing. After I changed my query, this script worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to filter the results after receiving response from the php file. You can do that by referring to the code below. Feel free to make required changes as per your need.

```js
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
  source: function(data, cb) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        // name:data.term
      },
      success: function(res) {
        //cb(res);

        var d = $.map(res, function(row) {
          return {
            label: row.name,
            value: row.name,
            name: row.name,
            email: row.email,
            website: row.website
          }
        });

        // to filter between items returned from $.map
        var filtered = d.filter(function(entry) {
          return entry.name.indexOf(data.term) > -1;
        })

        cb(filtered);
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).val(ui.item.value)
    $('#email').val(ui.item.email)
    $('#website').val(ui.item.website);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha256-rByPlHULObEjJ6XQxW/flG2r+22R5dKiAoef+aXWfik=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="search name">
<hr>
<input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email">
<input type="text" id="website" placeholder="website">
```

Comment: If you dont have any chance to edit PHP script, then @Neel's answer is the best way to go.!!

Comment: The answer is great, but my problem was at the database side, so I can't accept it, because it would not solve my problem.

Comment: @AME i asked if your api was programmed to do the matching in the comments. anyways, congratulations.